# How I can rename file name when I share PDF base64 string via UIActivityViewController in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova-plugins

I got PDF base64 string from server, It looks like this:

> "data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0x...."

Now I would like to share this file. I am using Cordova social share plugin, it works well. 
But how can I assign the file name? now, it only shows default name like "**PDF document.pdf**"

```
//activityItems is the base64 string
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:applicationActivities];
```

[image]

Comment: What does `UIActivityController` have to do with your question?

Comment: just for social share.

Answer (score 1):

You have two option to do this functionality.

1) You can Rename your file in Document Directory.

2) You can change your file name when you are going to save it in Document Directory.

1) How to change the filename in Document Directory:

```
- (BOOL)renameFileFrom:(NSString*)oldName to:(NSString *)newName
{
    NSString *documentDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                   NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *oldPath = [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:oldName];
    NSString *newPath = [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:newName];

    NSFileManager *fileMan = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![fileMan moveItemAtPath:oldPath toPath:newPath error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to move '%@' to '%@': %@", oldPath, newPath, [error localizedDescription]);
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

2) How to change the filename at the time of save File into Document Directory:

```
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory 
         inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}

NSString *path = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory].path 
                       stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"fileName.pdf"];
[sampleText writeToFile:path atomically:YES
                       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Comment: Thankssssssss! 

Comment: @DESTINY〆 If it is working you can give a review for this.

Comment: This only works if it was first saved to file, sharing it as is doesn't work, correct?

Comment: You have to give proper path.
NSString *documentDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                   NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

If you are using this. It will return 0 index file path from your document directory. Please give proper path of your file.
@CyberMew

Answer (score 0):

Save the file from URL to a temp directory and then use it in the UIActivityViewController

```
let temporaryDir = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory
let tempFilePath = temporaryDir.appendingPathComponent(pass the file name you want to show here)
do {
    try? Data(contentsOf: pass the file URL here).write(to: tempFilePath, options: .atomic)
  }
  
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems:  [tempFilePath], applicationActivities: nil)
present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```